# Compiling AVLD on 11.04

Tags: 11.04, video, compiling, kernel-modules

I'm trying to install [AVLD 1.4](http://allonlinux.free.fr/Projets/AVLD/) on Natty.

I've unpacked the files, but when I compile them with `make`, it fails:

```
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic-pae/build M=/home/jmendeth/Downloads/avld_0.1.4 modules
make[1]: entering «/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic-pae»
  CC [M]  /home/jmendeth/Downloads/avld_0.1.4/video_device.o
/home/jmendeth/Downloads/avld_0.1.4/video_device.c:23:28: fatal error: linux/videodev.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/jmendeth/Downloads/avld_0.1.4/video_device.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/jmendeth/Downloads/avld_0.1.4] Error 2
make[1]: leaving «/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic-pae»
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried to install `libv4l-0` and `libv4l-dev`, but still the same error.
If I replace `linux/videodev.h` with `linux/videodev2.h` on the file, a lot of errors pop out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVLD doesn't appear to be maintained anymore.

A similar video loopback package exists in the repositories which you can install - its called `v4l2loopback-source`.

### Auto Install

First from a terminal, drop to a root shell

```
sudo su
```

If you havent installed kernel modules before with module-assistant run the following from a terminal

```
apt-get install module-assistant
m-a prepare
m-a update
```

Finally - download and install `v4l2loopback`

```
m-a a-i v4l2loopback
exit
```

### Manual Install

Download the package - once installed it can be found in `/usr/src/v4l2loopback.tar.bz2`

Copy the package to, for example your ~/Downloads folder
compile and install

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvf v4l2loopback.tar.bz2
cd modules/v4l2loopback
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

This will create a /dev/video0 or /dev/video1 (etc) device.

Comment: Or install it with `module-assistant`.

Comment: ... excellent pointer @jmendeth

Comment: Anyway, how can I get AVLD (and similar apps which use V4L1) to compile in Ubuntu? What am I missing?

Comment: dont think you can - the v4l1 API was dropped with kernel 2.6.15.  If you've got a v4l1 only app, have you tried the old trick `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so <appname>` ?

Answer (score 0):

`linux/videodev.h` is now in `libv4l1-videodev.h`, in 11.04 change this `#include`
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1047

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Thank you.