# Fake a webcam using a video loopback device?

Tags: 12.04, video, webcam

I want to use a looped video clip as my webcam source in a Google+ Hangout. I installed v4l2loopback and created a [video loopback device](https://askubuntu.com/a/54055/37450). But I haven't figured out how to write the video frames to the device. The given [example](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki) is:

```
gst-launch videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

So after reading the manual page for gst-launch and trying to understand what was going on, I made my feeble attempt:

```
sudo gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/home/briankb/Videos/darthvaderdancing.mp4 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

Which resulted in:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libv4l2: error getting pixformat: Invalid argument
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...

(gst-launch-0.10:12622): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_get_structure: assertion `GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed
New clock: GstSystemClock

(gst-launch-0.10:12622): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_structure_get_name: assertion `structure != NULL' failed
Caught SIGSEGV accessing address (nil)
#0  0x00007fc1890f0b03 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fc18962bff6 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fc18962c45a in g_main_loop_run ()
#3  0x00007fc189b5c4cb in gst_bus_poll ()
#4  0x0000000000404587 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000403c34 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fc18902b76d in __libc_start_main ()
#7  0x00000000004043bd in ?? ()
#8  0x00007fff88253ed8 in ?? ()
#9  0x000000000000001c in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000000000006 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fff882548c4 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007fff882548d4 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007fff882548dc in ?? ()
#14 0x00007fff88254904 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007fff88254906 in ?? ()
#16 0x00007fff8825490f in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Spinning.  Please run 'gdb gst-launch 12622' to continue debugging, Ctrl-C to quit, or Ctrl-\ to dump core.
```

The clip I'm trying to use an h264 video at 29.97 fps, 320x240, and in an mp4 container (it's from Youtube).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `gst-launch` manpages tells us that we need to decode the video first, and the easiest way to do so is like this:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=[location] ! decodebin ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video0
```

`gst-launch` does not need to be run as root, and `[location]` can be relative too!

Answer (score 11):

Just use [v4l2loopback with mplayer](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/wiki/Mplayer).

1. Download it,
2. compile it (`make` and `su -c 'make install'`),
3. load the module with `su -c 'modprobe v4l2loopback'`,
4. then change one line in the file `examples/yuv4mpeg_to_v4l2.c` of the v4l2loopback source folder from

   ```
   v.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUV420;
   ```

   to

   ```
   v.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_YVU420;
   ```
5. and do `make` in this folder.
6. Then run it from the `examples` directory like this:

   ```
   mkfifo /tmp/pipe  # only needed once, as long as you do not delete the file /tmp/pipe
   ./yuv4mpeg_to_v4l2 < /tmp/pipe &
   mplayer movie.mp4 -vf scale=480:360 -vo yuv4mpeg:file=/tmp/pipe
   ```

   where you replace `movie.mp4` with the name of your video file. And replace `/dev/video0` with your loopback device.

MPlayer is able to play any webstreams, all kind of video files and so on. I just tested it with a file from http://www.tagesschau.de which is a german news site.

```
TS=$(wget 'http://www.tagesschau.de'$(wget http://www.tagesschau.de -q -O - | grep 'Letzte Sendung' | sed -e 's%.*href="%%' -e 's%".*%%') -q -O - | grep '\.webm\.webm' | sed -e 's%.*href="%%' -e 's%\.webm\.webm".*%.webm.webm%')
./yuv4mpeg_to_v4l2 < /tmp/pipe &
mplayer $TS -vf scale=480:360 -vo yuv4mpeg:file=/tmp/pipe
```

Comment: This answer says to change v.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_YVU420;
 to the exact same thing so does that mean no change is necessary?

Comment: @kkron: compare the two lines (before and after) character by character, and you will notice the difference. ;-) Hint: YUV and YVU.