# how to create a duplicate of /dev/video0?

Tags: webcam

I have 1 webcam connected to my computer but I want to use it in multiple programs.
The problem is when I launch a second program, it tells me the webcam is already used.

The programs which will use the webcam are : motion, pam_face_authentification, and some communication software like skype, google hangout ...

How can I duplicate the flow of my webcam to simulate a second webcam?

Comment: I do not understand what you are telling me ?

Comment: stream to a file, and to the display. you could do this with vlc, possibly cheese. once you have a stream, anything could use it.

Comment: Why not do it on OS start? Through "Startup Applications".

Answer (score 9):

My first thoughts were, I wonder if anyone has come up with a way to have a video appear as a webcam (e.g. I'm skyping with someone, but the video and audio they see is some video I chose instead). After searching around a bit, it looks like people have done this video piping (as discussed on [Manipulating Dev Video](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5452/manipulating-dev-video) and [Fake a webcam using a video loopback device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139239/)

As mentioned in your comment, `gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1` allows you to duplicate *video0* to *video1*, and *video1* is readable by some software.

In order to have this run when your computer starts, you can follow the [UbuntuBootupHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) to come up with something like:

```
# /etc/init/videocloner.conf
description "VideoCloner"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
exec gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1
```

This script should start when the computer boots and also allows you to run `sudo service videocloner start|stop` *(Note: if my example script doesn't work, try moving `gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1` into a shell script, and changing the `exec` line to call your shell script instead)*.

Comment: I want to add something to Dolan's answer. You also need to install the ```v4l2loopback-dkms``` package and run the ```v4l2loopback``` module: `sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms` and then `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`

Comment: I have tried this, but the result is I have a usable /dev/video1, but an unsusable /dev/video0, so it doesn't allow me to have two programs use the same physical webcam. I tried modifying the command to create /dev/vidoe1 and /dev/video2 so I have 2 endpoints, but no luck.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343832/how-to-read-a-webcam-that-is-already-used-by-a-background-capture