# How can I broadcast a local video file as a webcam feed?

Tags: webcam, video-streaming

I want to broadcast a local video file `file.avi` as if it were a webcam via a flash-based broadcasting system inside Google Chrome on a public website (a-la ustream).

Comment: You probably would be able to use [`v4l2loopback`](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) or similar for this - also this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139239/fake-a-webcam-using-a-video-loopback-device

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/

Install and don't forget to run

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/video*
```

This will allow you to use avi, flv, gif, and other animation sources as a virtual webcam.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about using Google plus live streaming to do this? 
It's easy to stream anything in your hangouts and with a screen recording software you can stream any video file that you may have.

Check [these instructions](http://jefflebow.net/streaming-recording-google-plus-hangout):