# How to create a virtual video device in ubuntu

Tags: server, video, webcam

I have a local server which just publish video to a address http://localhost:8080

I can get the video on any browser in the local network.
Is there a way to create a virtual video device which will use the video published at that address as input and can be accessed by any webcam application or video chatting application.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is called a "video loopback" device you may get lucky with this. Here is the link:http://allonlinux.free.fr/Projets/AVLD/ Let me know if it's working

Comment: AVLD didn't worked .I used v4l2loopback  virtual device < .https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback >  But i cannot put my video url < http://localhost:8080 > as input . But I created a vitual video device /dev/video1  and loopbacked the video on /dev/video0  to newly created video device.

Comment: Still dosen't solve my problem

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/139239/fake-a-webcam-using-a-video-loopback-device