# Is there any way ffmpeg send video to /dev/video0 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to send video to webcam device on Ubuntu which is loaded on /dev/video0

I've already seen this command that send desktop to it but is there any way to send video to it?

> ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo
>   -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0

I should mention that i specifically want to use ffmpeg command.

Comment: It's my understanding that a webcam is an video input device so I would say no. What webcam do you have that supports receiving video?

Comment: @ElderGeek there is no webcam.it is virtual one which need to have video on it.

Comment: HAve you tried using a pipe?

Comment: Information is available [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Output-Devices)

Comment: @ElderGeek yes and i face the error "pipe broken".

Comment: @ElderGeek i saw that information, it is confusing for me and i think i need some ffmpeg expert to help me for the command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fake a webcam using a video loopback device?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139239/fake-a-webcam-using-a-video-loopback-device) (although not necessarily using `ffmpeg`).

Comment: Based on a quick review of the link I provided you it appears that you would have to compile a configured  ffmpeg build from source to enable the specific output devices that you intend to use as outlined in the section I linked you to. I understand that you want to accomplish this with ffmpeg, however you might wish to ease your requirements in order to obtain an answer that is within your capabilities.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do this with [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback). First you need to install it:

## Install v4l2loopback

### Method 1: Install v4l2loopback from the repository

```
sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

This is easy but older versions of v4l2loopback have some known bugs, so consider compiling it instead if you encounter any issues.

### Method 2: Compile v4l2loopback

If it's not in the repository for your Ubuntu version, or you want the latest version, you can compile it:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
wget https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/archive/main.zip
unzip main.zip
cd v4l2loopback-main
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=v4l2loopback --pkgversion="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --default
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

#### Uninstalling

If you want to remove the package you compiled:

```
sudo apt-get remove v4l2loopback
```

---

## Examples

**Note that the actual `video` number may vary depending if an existing device is already using `/dev/video0`.** Check output of `ls /dev/video*` or `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`.

### Desktop to virtual camera

Now run `ffmpeg`. Example for desktop using [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab):

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 15 -video_size 1280x720 -i :0.0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

### Video file (MP4) to virtual camera

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

### Image to virtual camera

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -i input.jpg -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

### Webcam → ffmpeg → Virtual webcam

#### Add text

With [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -vf "drawtext=text='Hello World':fontsize=12:fontcolor=white:font=Arial:x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10,format=yuv420p" -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

See [How to position drawtext text?](https://superuser.com/a/939386/)

#### Greenscreen / chroma key / replace background

Using [chromakey](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#chromakey), [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay), and [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filters:

```
ffmpeg -re -i background.jpg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -filter_complex "[1]chromakey=color=#326964:similarity=0.07:blend=0.02[fg];[0][fg]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:format=auto,format=yuv420p" -f v4l2 /dev/video1
```

See [How to position overlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/)

### Preview with `ffplay`

```
ffplay /dev/video0
```

---

## Common errors

- Unable to open V4L2 device '/dev/video0'
- Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
- Unknown V4L2 pixel format equivalent for yuvj422p

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1232042/) for solutions.

Comment: where can i specify my video ?

Comment: @dsddd Example updated.

Comment: I installed the package,  but I'm stuck with an error on both examples, either the x11grab or the the mp4 video give me the same `[v4l2 @ 0x55ebc0cfdc40] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
`

Is there something else I should do? some dependencies I missed?

Comment: @Sabbin Please show your command and provide a link to a pastebin of the log.

Comment: @llogan following your example above, I have this command `ffmpeg -re -i 1.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0` https://pastebin.com/9eDK0NTN, if I try the command to run for desktop `ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 15 -video_size 1280x720 -i :1 -f v4l2 /dev/video0` I get this error https://pastebin.com/xN6uZJR6, also the folder /dev/video0 has rights for write

Comment: @Sabbin I guess it didn't compile/install correctly, but there is now a package available so compiling isn't required anymore. Do this: `sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback && sudo apt remove v4l2loopback && sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms && sudo modprobe v4l2loopback` and try again with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @llogan I had the `v4l2loopback-dkms` installed from before. I tried the above command and I still get the same results

Comment: @Sabbin I can't duplicate the issue. Works for me on 18.04 using v4l2loopback-dkms and ffmpeg from repository.

Comment: @llogan, I will remove everything and try to get it from 0 again, maybe I missed or have done something wrong. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @sabbin try with /dev/video1

Comment: Now how do I get the device to show up to e.g. Chrome software?

Comment: @Michael Worth asking that as a new question.

Comment: @llogan Thanks, [done](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238346/how-to-get-v4l2-loopback-device-to-be-recognized)

Comment: another error I had was that `snap` installed `ffmpeg` didn't have access to video feed. The command `snap connect ffmpeg:camera` fixed it

Comment: wayland compatible solution?

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck Sorry, but I don't know anything about wayland.

Comment: maybe I found something here, will try later
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Screen_capture#Wayland