# Problem setting dslr up as webcam

Tags: video, webcam, ffmpeg, video4linux, gphoto2

I am trying to set up my nikon d7000 dslr as a video device for Ubuntu 18.04, as shown [in this article](https://medium.com/nerdery/dslr-webcam-setup-for-linux-9b6d1b79ae22).

When I try to start the video stream/device with

```
gphoto2 --capture-movie --stdout | ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

The Error I get:

```
:~$ gphoto2 --capture-movie --stdout | ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.

[mjpeg @ 0x5556d09cd9c0] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, 1 reference frame, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, center), 640x426, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x5556d09e0cc0] w:640 h:426 pixfmt:yuvj422p tb:1/1200000 fr:25/1 sar:0/1 sws_param:flags=2
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x5556d09e88e0] w:iw h:ih flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[format @ 0x5556d09e5e60] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'format'
[swscaler @ 0x5556d09e99c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x5556d09e88e0] w:640 h:426 fmt:yuvj422p sar:0/1 -> w:640 h:426 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x4
[v4l2 @ 0x5556d09d7980] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
Conversion failed!
```

Info about the Camera:

```
:~$ gphoto2 --auto-detect
Model                          Port                                            
----------------------------------------------------------
Nikon DSC D7000 (PTP mode)     usb:001,005    
:~$ gphoto2 --summary
Camera summary:                                                                
Manufacturer: Nikon Corporation
Model: D7000
  Version: V1.03
  Serial Number:
Vendor Extension ID: 0xa (1.0)
Vendor Extension Description: microsoft.com: 1.0

Capture Formats: JPEG Undefined Type
Display Formats: JPEG, Undefined Type, Association/Directory, DPOF, Script, Apple Quicktime

Device Capabilities:
        File Download, File Deletion, File Upload
        Generic Image Capture, No Open Capture, Nikon Capture 1, Nikon Capture 2, Nikon Capture 3
[...]
```

I spent some time in the man pages of these commands, without luck. I am still not sure where the problem is exactly. The camera appears to be sending a stream, at least the mirror goes up and when I try the command without the ffmpeg stuff I get a Terminal full of Garbage, witch is Image data in Text form, I presume.

Maybe I set the v4l2 device up wrong?

How can I check what is working and what is not? Maybe I have to tell the v4l2 exactly what it should do?

Can anybody help me with gphoto + ffmpeg + video4linux or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Two posts today about the same error. I suspect a problem with v4l2loopback (but I'm not sure). Try removing the v4l2loopback-dkms package and [compile v4l2loopback](https://askubuntu.com/a/881341/59378).

Comment: Indeed, ther might be a bug .. https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/172#issuecomment-392380155

Comment: It may be an issue with v4l2loopback. I run Ubuntu eoan (which is newer than yours) and I added the release numbers of my ffmpeg and vl2loopback (whitch are OK) to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that /dev/video0 was the right device to use ?

I tested this kind of setup an found that I had 3 video devices.

/dev/video0 is my laptop's webcam.
I don't know what /dev/video1 is.

**/dev/video2** is my dslr through gphoto2.

I launched gphoto2 with this command and everything worked as intended.

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

Maybe you have a bug which have been fixed in eoan packages. I run :

- ffmpeg 7:4.1.4-1build2
- v4l2loopback 0.12.2-1

Comment: No, the outcome is the same, regardless of what video out I specify. Also there is no other camera on this PC (not a laptop)

Comment: You will still get the same error: `[mjpeg @ 0x740a940] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!`

Comment: This helped me. It was `/dev/video4` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Run `rmmod v4l2loopback` and then list all video devices using `ls /dev/video*` and note all devices
2. Run `modprob v4l2loopback` and then list all video devices again using `ls /dev/video*`see which device is been added compared to the output you got in #1 and use that newly added device in your gphoto2 command

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same problem with a Canon EOS RP; I did every step correctly but the error kept appearing to me.

So I changed the camera setting from video (shooting) mode to photo mode and everything works fine.