# Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory

Tags: sound, video, ffmpeg

I have been trying to setup my DSLR to be a webcam with the following command: `gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0` this however results in the following error:

```bsh
hutber@hutber:~/v4l2loopback-master$ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video4
ffmpeg version N-49161-g50e194e6e1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
[mjpeg @ 0x6d04900] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x426, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x6d07d00] Unable to open V4L2 device '/dev/video4'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

However this errors to create the dummy device, that at the same time is not accessible

```bsh
hutber@hutber:~/v4l2loopback-master$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video2

Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

I would like the /dev/video0 to be available to use as a webcam and believe the issue lies somewhere in the v412.

**[Edit]**

After restarting the machine I now see:

```bsh
hutber@hutber:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory
```

It says there is a Dummy Video Device, but I cannot see any devices when trying to use the dummy video.

[image]

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback` as shown in [Is there any way ffmpeg send video to `/dev/video0` on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/881341/) and then show output from `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`.

Comment: Thanks Llogan, I see you're helping on both quesitons. Thank you. I have updated with a screenshot.

Comment: If I reset my machine, then the `Dummy video device` will no longer be there, but I will still experience the same errors when trying to pipe through to ffmpeg

Comment: Now try `gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -c:v rawvideo -f v4l2 /dev/video0`

Comment: Thanks again, new error: `[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x589f700] Unknown V4L2 pixel format equivalent for yuvj422p`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use webcam from laptop on desktop pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225088/use-webcam-from-laptop-on-desktop-pc)

Comment: I think the step that I was missing is `sudo modprobe v412loopback` llogan. With a refresh restart. Thank you again

Answer (score 8):

## Unable to open V4L2 device '/dev/video0'

#### or

## Failed to open /dev/video0: No such file or directory

Two potential problems:

- Wrong `video` number. The number can change depending on the number of existing webcams. Check output of `ls /dev/video*` or `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`.
- v4l2loopback module is not enabled or installed. If you already installed v4l2loopback run `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`. Then check output of `ls /dev/video*` or `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`. If you did not yet install it see [Is there any way ffmpeg send video to `/dev/video0` on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/881341/).

## Unknown V4L2 pixel format equivalent for yuvj422p

The V4L2 output device only supported a limited number of *pixel formats*. Add the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) to your command to give it a compatible pixel format:

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that my `ffmpeg` was installed by snap and didn't originally have access to camera.

Running

```
snap connect ffmpeg:camera
```

fixed it.