# Use custom video to feed camera

Tags: webcam, ffmpeg, camera, zoom-meeting, v4l

What I am trying to achive is to redirect my camera `/dev/video0` with a custom video file.

**Desired Reasult:**

When opened a application like cheese or websites like jitsi which process the buffer from my camera. Is it possible to use already captured video file as camera input.

**Previous attempt:**

I followed a answer from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881305/is-there-any-way-ffmpeg-send-video-to-dev-video0-on-ubuntu) but i am getting a error message as

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x556927267880] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

on executing the command

```
ffmpeg -re -i ~/Videos/Webcam/sample.webm -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```

Comment: hi please edit your question and add the command that produces the error.

Comment: I just did. Could you see that again?

Comment: If you follow the steps for PC here https://askubuntu.com/a/1227239 and skip the net cat part and use your video file as the source for the included `ffmpeg `command… you should be good to go.

Comment: Please run `apt policy v4l2loopback-utils v4l2loopback-dkms` and check your installed version... `0.12.2-1` works fine but earlier and later versions have issues. The kind of error you get tells me you most likely have a version grater than `0.12.2-1` installed... I have seen this error before.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved after a couple of hours. On [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881305/is-there-any-way-ffmpeg-send-video-to-dev-video0-on-ubuntu) the /dev/video0 was actually representing the virtual camera created by v4l2loopback but in my case as I am on laptop /dev/video0 actually points to integrated webcam. So what I did is:

```
ls /dev/video*
```

And note the devices returned now you can load the module like

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

and now a new device pointer should be preset. Check it by

```
ls /dev/video*
```

Notice the new device added and that's what you have to work with. Keeping this in mind now you can follow [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881305/is-there-any-way-ffmpeg-send-video-to-dev-video0-on-ubuntu).

Comment: This was already mentioned in the answer you linked to: "Note that the actual video number may vary depending if an existing device is already using `/dev/video0`. Check output of `ls /dev/video*` or `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`".