# Built in camera not recognized

Tags: 22.04, camera, ubuntu-drivers

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in ThinkPad X1 Carbon and when I open cheese it shows "No device found".
I don't think that the problem is Cheese, because when searching for a camera via terminal, it can't be found. I also checked BIOS and the camera is enabled (I can use it in Windows).

I think it must be a missing driver, so I searched for a solution.
Following instructions, running `sudo ubuntu-drivers list` returns nothing,
`sudo ubuntu-drivers install` returns `All the available drivers are already installed` and `sudo apt install nvidia-fabricmanager-525 libnvidia-nscq-525` returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree... Done   
Reading state information... Done   
libnvidia-nscq-525 is already the newest version (525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).    
nvidia-fabricmanager-525 is already the newest version (525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
```

Can someone help me find the missing driver or give me any tip?

lsusb returns:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 06cb:00fc Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 1050:0407 Yubico.com Yubikey 4/5 OTP+U2F+CCID
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Open a terminal. Run `lsusb`. Read the output - locate which item on the list is your camera. Edit your question above to add the complete output.

Comment: Add yourself to the `video` group with the terminal command `sudo adduser $USER video`, then logout/login. Groups are set up at login.

Comment: Thank you @waltinator, now my computer recognizes the camera. Camera still don't work but it's a new problem.
I also added the lsusb output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `sudo adduser $USER video`, I've followed this:
[Is there any way ffmpeg send video to /dev/video0 on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881305/is-there-any-way-ffmpeg-send-video-to-dev-video0-on-ubuntu)

and by running `ffplay /dev/video0` I have video now.

It isn't perfect, but works.
To have camera in Teams, I run that in terminal, and then turn the camera on in Teams.
If someone has another solution, please share :)